# MVC3 Linq select top 5 of each category

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am trying to select and display the most recent 5 submissions of each news category in a partial view.  the news table has category Id as foreign key.  I have this code below but it displays nothing on testing.  could anyone assist.

Code in News Controller

```
public ActionResult _HomeCatNews()
{
    var info = db.News
        .GroupBy(r => r.CatId)
        .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(r => r.RevDate)
        .Take(5))
        .ToList();
    return PartialView();
}
```

Partial view view code is as below

```
@model IEnumerable<KPortal.Models.HomeNewzCat>
@using KPortal.Helpers

@foreach (var item in Model) {        
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewsPic)</a>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <h5><a href="#">@Html.Raw(Html.Truncate(item.NewsContent, 55, ""))</a></h5>
                <span class="date">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RevisionDate)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewSource)
                </span>
            </div> 
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewsTitle)
        </li>                           
    </ul>
}
```

HomeNewzCat Model

```
namespace KPortal.Models
{
    public class HomeNewzCat
    {
        [Display(Name = "Category ID")]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Revision Date")]
        public DateTime RevisionDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "News Title")]
        public string NewsTitle { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Story Picture")]
        public string NewsPic { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        [Display(Name = "News Content")]
        public string NewsContent { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Source")]
        public string NewSource { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, move your `<ul>` tags outside of the `foreach` loop and also add a check for if there are no records returned

```
@if(Model != null) {
    <ul>
        @foreach(var item in Model) {
           <li>
               <div class="image">
                   <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewsPic)</a>
               </div>
               <div class="details">
                   <h5><a href="#">@Html.Raw(Html.Truncate(item.NewsContent, 55, ""))</a></h5>
                   <span class="date">
                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RevisionDate)
                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewSource)
                   </span>
               </div> 
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewsTitle)
           </li>   
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Next we need to build a list of `HomeNewzCat` to send to the partial view

```
public ActionResult _HomeCatNews()
{
    var info = db.News
        .GroupBy(r => r.CatId)
        .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(r => r.RevDate)
        .Take(5))
        .ToList();

    var model = new List<HomeNewzCat>();
    HomeNewzCat record = null;

    // first make sure we have some records
    if(info.Count() > 0) {
        foreach(var item in info) {
            // you will need to modify these item.Field to match your database names
            record = new HomeNewzCat 
                         {
                             CategoryID = item.CatID,
                             Category = item.Category,
                             RevisionDate = item.RevDate,
                             NewsTitle = item.NewsTitle,
                             NewsPic = item.NewsPic,
                             NewsContent = item.NewsContent,
                             NewsSource = item.NewsSource,
                             Date = item.Date
                         };
            model.Add(record);
        }
    }
    return PartialView("_HomeCatNewz", model);
}
```

Comment: thanks very much @AlfalfaStrange I am trying to implement your solution but I am getting errors what goes to YourPartialView I was thinking _HomeCatNews()

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you update your question with the code you are trying? Is your partial view named "_HomeCatNews.cshtml"? If so you should use `return PartialView("_HomeCatNews", model);` and it should be in the same views folder as the view it's being loaded into or in the Shared folder so it can be found.

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KPortal.Models.News]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[KPortal.Models.HomeNewzCat]'.

Comment: You're sending in the wrong kind of model, the partial view requires a list of `HomeNewzCat` not a List of `News`

Comment: Update your question by posting the code for your partial view and your `HomeNewzCat` view model.

Comment: I did as requested now the error i get is a NullReference excepton; Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in the _HomeCatNewz Partial view page at the @foreach(var item in model) line

Comment: Updated the answer based upon partial view and view model code

Comment: thanks very much for your support. It runs without errors but returns no results and I am wondering why

Comment: Most likely because the query isn't returning any results, you will need to look at that part now and figure out why the query isn't finding any matched results in your database. If you have experience with SQL Profiler you can capture the SQL statement being executed and use that to troubleshoot your database

Comment: I finally found out why the query was not returning results. I am using MySQL and the .take(n) parameter is not supported by MySQL yet [MySQL Bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64749)

Comment: Well, yea I could see where that might be a problem :-) You should be able to use this then `var info = db.News
        .GroupBy(r => r.CatId)
        .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(r => r.RevDate))
        .ToList().Take(5);`

Comment: This isn't ideal as it returns all the data to the client and then the client takes the top 5

Comment: Thanks @AlfalfaStrange  The application's database can stay within 10GB for now so I have switched the database to MSSQL Express